# PHP Guzzle client for HTTP keep-alive

Tags: php, httpclient, keep-alive, guzzle

I am trying to connect to an API that keeps the connection alive and sends the chunked data.

I have a solution that uses fsockopen which writes and reads the stream and uses `while(!$stream->eof())`.

I am wondering if I can use Guzzle to acheive the same result?

I saw the Async method but can some show me how to wait for stream?

Answer (score 2):

Guzzle 6+ supports [PRS-7](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/docs/psr7.rst), which defines a response body as a stream. You can request data synchronously or asynchronously, it doesn't matter.

Also it's important to set [`stream` option](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#stream) for your request:

```
$client = new Client(/* ... */);

$response = $client->get('http://some.url/', ['stream' => true]);
$bodyStream = $response->getBody();

while (!$bodyStream->eof()) {
    echo $bodyStream->read(1024);
}
```